# best way of resending data for pagination search result

Tags: php, pagination

I wonna know that what is the best way to resend the data(search inputs) for the search result page and paginate it ? for example ,for the first time , I post data from page a.php to b.php , so in b.php I got the posted data and do pagination,and next time I wonna go to second page with the same posted data , what should I do ?? is it the best way to send inputs to url ?? 
like this : `<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>?page=2&name=<?php echo $name?>&family=<?php echo $family;?>&otherParametersHere"><?php echo $page_number?></a>`

is it good ?? but what if I had more than 10 or 15 inputs ? I thought that it s not suitable to send 15 inputs through url and GET them .
plz make me clear .thanks in advance

Comment: For all of my pagination needs I use server sided datatables. If this solution does not work for you, then i suggest reading the server side processing script for datatables which handles pagination to find the way to do it. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: its a good way ,thanks for help :-) but what do u think of my way ? what is the best to send these data ?

Comment: I would sanitize your $name and $family value with htmlentities that escapes double quotes, add additional metric called '$results_per_page', or just pass all values from all filters in json_encoded string which will solve your additional inputs issue.

Comment: yes of course I sanitize parameters with htmlentities and escape them from some strings , but my question is , is it good to send it to url ? or another way , like ,storing them in sessions (seen somewhere ... ),or another ways ... ?

Comment: Generally speaking, storing them in URL is best for user experience. If someone wants to share a link to your results, they will be able to do so without any issues.

Comment: yes yes , nice point of view , thanks alot for that.